# Mixing roles into callables

Tags: mixins, raku

Theoretically, you can [mix in a role into an object in runtime](https://docs.raku.org/language/objects#Mixins_of_Roles). So I am trying to do this with a function:

```
my &random-f = -> $arg  { "Just $arg" };

say random-f("boo");

role Argable {
    method argh() {
        self.CALL-ME( "argh" );
    }
}

&random-f does Argable;

say random-f.argh;
```

Within the role, I use `self` to refer to the already defined function, and [`CALL-ME`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/CALL-ME) to actually call the function within the role. However, this results in the following error:

```
Too few positionals passed; expected 1 argument but got 0
in block <unit> at self-call-me.p6 line 5
```

I really have no idea who's expecting 1 argument. Theoretically, it should be the `CALL-ME` function, but who knows. Eliminating the `self.` yields a different error: `CALL-ME used at line 11`. Adding `does Callable` to `Argable` (after putting self back) results in the same error. Can this be done? Any idea of how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's two things incorrect in your code:

```
say random-f.argh;  # *call* random-f and then call .argh on the result
```

You want to call `.argh` on the `Callable` so:

```
say &random-f.argh;
```

Secondly, you should just be able to call `self`: you can tweak this in the signature of the `.argh` method:

```
method argh(&self:) {
```

So the final code becomes:

```
my &random-f = -> $arg  { "Just $arg" };

say random-f("boo");

role Argable {
    method argh(&self:) {
        self( "argh" );
    }
}

&random-f does Argable;

say &random-f.argh;
```